HTML и CSS. Надо сделать плавное появление (при появлении в пределах видимости элемента на сайте), а так же плавное исчезновение (при кхода из вида)
HTML и CSS. Надо сделать плавное появление (при появлении в пределах видимости элемента на сайте), а так же плавное исчезновение (при кхода из вида). Сказали сделать это именно на CSS и HTML.
Для <div id="first" class="section">Секция 1</div> и <div id="second" class="section">Секция 2</div>.
Кто знает, подскажите пожалуйста.

Почитайте про animation-timeline

Скажите тому, кто это сказал, что без javascript невозможно узнать, что элемент появился в пределах видимости. К примеру, у вас есть <footer> и нужно запустить анимацию при его появлении в пределах видимости... Откуда HTML это знать? А CSS, если что-то и знает, например position: sticky, то явно ничего не может сказать и сделать по этому поводу.
